# how to start (roadmap ) in my project for artificial intelligence

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

please help me how to start my studio project running in python (roadmap)

It is necessary to implement a model that analyzes posts from the social network Twitter and
recognizes whether they relate to a warning of an emergency, for example a weather
disaster. This model would be part of a system that would track Twitter user posts and generate them
warnings to the appropriate services. A dataset containing the text of the publication is available
keywords and location. Publications are classified as a realistic warning (Label 1) or not (Label 0).
External source: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nlp-getting-started/overview

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to implement a model that analyzes posts from the social network Twitter and recognizes whether they relate to a warning of an emergency, for example a weather disaster. This model would be part of a system that would track Twitter user posts and generate them warnings to the appropriate services. A dataset containing the text of the publication is available keywords and location. Publications are classified as a realistic warning (Label 1) or not (Label 0). External source: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nlp-getting-started/overview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsnqf.png)